# Pacemaker location constraints on resources apparently not obeyed

Tags: pacemaker, corosync, linux-ha

I have a Pacemaker setup with two STONITH resources. They have location constraints that `crm configure show` lists as follows:

```
location loc_stonith_node1 stonith_node1 rule -inf: #id eq node1
location loc_stonith_node2 stonith_node2 rule -inf: #id eq node2
```

Yet `crm status` indicates that both resources are started on `node2`:

```
stonith_node1   (stonith:external/ipmi):    Started node2
stonith_node2   (stonith:external/ipmi):    Started node2
```

This situation even persists if I `crm resource stop` and then `crm resource start` both resources. What could explain that the location constraints are apparently not obeyed?

**UPDATE** If I `crm resource migrate stonith_node2 node1`, the resource starts on `node1`, but if I then `crm resource unmigrate stonith_node2` it immediately bounces back to `node2`.

Comment: Please add the complete config, omit sensitive details, if needed.

Comment: @gf_ I guess by now the problem is that [`#id`](https://github.com/ClusterLabs/pacemaker/blob/master/xml/crm.dtd) refers to node ids such as `1`, whereas `#uname` refers to node names (host names) such as `node1`. I'll try whether switching to `#uname` makes a difference and will then report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've overcome the problem by switching to [another syntactic form](https://clusterlabs.org/doc/crm_fencing.html) for the location contraints that requires neither references to `#id` nor `#uname`:

```
location loc_stonith_node1 stonith_node1 -inf: node1
location loc_stonith_node2 stonith_node2 -inf: node2
```